# Why is the first conjugate time continuous on the unit tangent bundle?

Tags: riemannian-geometry

Let (M,g) be a complete, connected Riemmanian manifold and SM the unit tangent bundle. Define the map
$con:SM\to (0,\infty]$ such that for $v\in SM, con(v)$ is the first positive time such that $\gamma_v(con(v))$ is conjugate to $\gamma_v(0)$ along $\gamma_v$.Set $con(v)=\infty$ if no such time exists. (Here $\gamma_v$ is the geodesic with $\dot\gamma_v(0)=v$)
Does anybody have a reference for the continuity of con?

Comment: This, I believe, follows from the fact that, for a parameterized system of ODEs, the solutions to a specified initial value problem depend continuously on the parameter. The idea is to apply this to the Jacobi equation.

Comment: Thank you but in how far is this a initial value problem? Isn't it a boundary problem?